Gitlab Runner Service does not create a Working Directory
I started gitlab-runner as a service so that the instance is always running even on restart.
I can't seem to find the working directory assets after a build is complete. I can see the configurations for the service are as so:
/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --service gitlab-runner --user gitlab-runner
But when i go to /home/gitlab-runner it does not exist.
Oddly enough when I run gitlab-runner not as a service I can see the build assets in
/home/build_user/builds/a7x71jn8Y/0/git-group/git-repo
Why is running on service not providing build assets?

you can double check the /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-ci-multi-runner.service file for working-directory. By default, it is not /home/gitlab-runner and it is /var/lib/gitlab-runner

The file contains information that implies that /home/gitlab-runner is the working directory. ExecStart=/usr/bin/gitlab-runner "run" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--working-directory" "/home/gitlab-runner" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--user" "gitlab-runner"

Looks like starting the service was correct and the service file had correct information. The problem was that config.toml was not populated correctly.
I needed to copy the config.toml from /home/manual_run_user/.gitlab-runner/config.toml to /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
Restarting the service after the file copy resulted in the agent running properly.
